# Whitespace on tablet

Tags: bug, android-app, android-tablet-app

Just installed the Stackexchange app (v 1.0.95) on a Samsung Galaxy Tab S3, and the Feed screen looks like it's got way too much whitespace. I checked in landscape view also, and it's the same. Is there a setting I missed, is thus a bug, or is the app just unsupported for tablets with larger screens?

[image]

Comment: Don't bother with the Android App for viewing the site. It is useful for push notifications, but otherwise inferior to just using the website. It's also in maintenance mode, and unlikely to get any changes outside of critical bug fixes.

Comment: @Sensible the answer on the duplicate shows the very thing I'm bringing up here, formatting and whitespace still sucks

Comment: @CDspace to be fair, the answer in the dupe shouldn't be accepted (but it's self-answered anyway) because the bug is still there. But yeah, there's no one working on the mobile apps right now.